# Deploying Laravel 5 onto godaddy shared windows hosting with plesk

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've been looking through the forums and online for a guide on how to deploy Laravel 5 onto a godaddy windows hosting server with plesk but I wasn't able to find much information.  I was hoping someone here might be able to help me with that. Here is what I did:

1. First I downloaded a new laravel installation and extracted it to the root directory.
2. Then I moved the entire "public" folder from the "laravel" folder(that was recently created from the extraction) into the "httpdocs" folder.
3. After that I edited the "index.php" file which is located in the "public" folder so that the following two paths were correct:

   [image]
4. After that I tested to see if it succeeded by going to yourdomain.com/public
5. After I tried, I was shown the following error:
   Internal Server Error

"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Could someone tell me what I did wrong in setting up Laravel 5 for a godaddy web hosting account?  Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't show an error message.  Going to the domain /auth/login would just lead to a blank page

Comment: Hi! Did you work it out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @John123 Had you get resolved this issue or used any other hosting?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the answer but didn't get it over the internet. Later find it by debugging it in depth.

So thought to share it here, anyone else may get benefited.

Set display error to on in PHP Settings (as displayed in image).This will help to identify the issue behind Internal server error.

[Display Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFLMx.png)

Best Regards,
Bhavesh NJS